# Python Numpy Array returns multiple values for each index, yet does not allow indexing of those values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

When I print the array it looks like this

```
print(my_array)
[ 0 0 0 1 0 1...  
1 0 2 0 1 ]  
[ 0 0 0 1 0 1...  
1 0 2 0 1 ]  
none
```

When I index the array with a single index like

```
print(my_array[0])
```

it returns

```
0  
0  
none
```

but if I try, for example

```
print(my_array[0,0])
```

I get

```
"IndexError: too many indices for array"
```

Finally, the shape returns

```
(750,)  
(750,)  
None
```

and the type returns

```
class 'numpy.ndarray'   
class 'numpy.ndarray'  
None
```

This array was given to me as is for a homework assignment, so I don't know how it was made (Coursera Course). How can I split the three arrays? I can see that each 750 data points are repeats, and I just need one set of the 750 to use for the assignment.

Comment: The array is 1d with `object` dtype.  Like a list is contains pointers to other arrays.  It's not a 2d array (matrix) but rather more like a list of lists.

Answer (score 1):

Your array has dtype `object` because it's not a numeric array with the same number of columns in each row. It looks something like this:

```
L = [np.array([0, 0, 1]), np.array([0, 0, 0]), None]

A = np.array(L)

array([array([0, 0, 1]),
       array([0, 0, 0]),
       None], dtype=object)

for i in A:
    print(type(i))    

<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'NoneType'>
```

That's not how you should use NumPy. You can try removing the `None` values to construct a regular NumPy numeric array:

```
B = np.array([i for i in L if i is not None])

array([[0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

If in doubt, check the `dtype` of an array to check it has the correct type:

```
A.dtype  # dtype('O')
B.dtype  # dtype('int32')
```